# Plotting dr4pl dose response curves, and how to integrate them with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set up a high-throughput way of plotting out dose response curves from a large screening experiment. Prism obviously has the easiest way of doing dose-response curves well, but I can't copy and paste this much data.

Since CRAN removed `drc`, the package `dr4pl` seems the way to go, but there is very little instruction available yet.

```
#make data frame 
dose <- c("0.078125","0.156250","0.312500","0.625000","1.250000","2.500000","5.000000","10.000000","20.000000")
POC<-c("1.05637425", "0.87380081", "0.79171200", "0.83166848", "0.77361290", "0.35199288", "0.19404609",  "0.09079221", "0.09850658")
data<-data.frame(dose, POC)


#use the dr4pl pakcage to calculate curve and IC50 etc
model<-dr4pl(POC~dose, data)

summary.model <- summary(model)

summary.model$coefficients

#plot this
plot(dr4pl(POC~dose, data=data))
```

[image: plot coded above]

The above will generate the type of curve I need using dr4pl, and get me the IC50. but how would I plot several datasets/curves on one plot?

Ideally I'd rather plot the data using ggplot2: `plot+geom_point()` and add in the dose response line by using the dr4pl summary as a `+stat_smooth()` model, if that makes sense? But I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: OP, can you supply a dataset or in this case, two datasets that allow us to reproduce the plots and help demonstrate how to combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can get most of the way but not all the way.  The main step is to write a `predict()` method for `dr4pl` objects:

```r
predict.dr4pl <- function (object, newdata=NULL, se.fit=FALSE, level, interval) {
    xseq <- if (is.null(newdata)) object$data$Dose else newdata$x
    pred <- MeanResponse(xseq, object$parameters)
    if (!se.fit) {
        return(pred)
    }
    qq <- qnorm((1+level)/2)
    se <- sapply(xseq,
                 function(x) car::deltaMethod(object, 
    "UpperLimit + (LowerLimit - UpperLimit)/(1 + (x/IC50)^Slope)")[["Estimate"]])
    return(list(fit=data.frame(fit=pred,lwr=pred-qq*se,
                                upr=pred+qq*se), se.fit=se))
}
```

I included a slightly hacky way to compute the confidence intervals via the delta method - this might not be too reliable (bootstrapping would be better ...)

It works OK (sort of) for your data (changed the name to `dd` because it's sometimes dicey to name the data `data` (`fortunes::fortune("dog")`)).

```r
dd <- data.frame(dose = c(0.078125,0.156250,0.312500,0.625000,1.25,
                          2.50,5.0,10.0,20.0),
                 POC = c(1.05637425, 0.87380081, 0.79171200,
                         0.83166848, 0.77361290, 0.35199288,
                         0.19404609,  0.09079221, 0.09850658))

library(dr4pl)
ggplot(dd, aes(dose,POC)) + geom_point() +
     geom_smooth(method="dr4pl",se=TRUE) + coord_trans(x="log10")
```

[image: 4-parameter logistic curve]

- the confidence intervals are terrible, turn them off with `se=FALSE`
- `dr4pl` puts the x-axis on a log10-scale by default, but the standard `scale_x_log10()` screws this up because it is applied *before* the fitting and prediction, so I use `coord_trans(x="log10")` instead.
- However, `coord_trans()` doesn't play so nicely if the axes are on a very broad logarithmic scale - I tried the example above with the `sample_data_1` data from the package and it didn't work.

But I'm afraid I've spent enough time on this for now.

It would more robust to use the `predict` method above to generate the values you want, over the range you want, separately, and then use `geom_line()` + `geom_ribbon()` to add the information to the plot ....

If you're willing to fit the model first (outside `geom_smooth`) you can do this (this is using `sample_data_1` from `dr4pl` package - it's from the first example in `?dr4pl`)

```r
model2 <- dr4pl(dose = sample_data_1$Dose,
           response = sample_data_1$Response)

ggplot(sample_data_1, aes(Dose,Response)) + geom_point() +
    stat_function(fun=function(x) predict(model2,newdata=data.frame(x=x))) +
    scale_x_log10()
```

which is less sensitive to the order of scaling/unscaling the x axis.

---

Improved but slow bootstrap CIs:

```r
predictdf.dr4pl <- function (model, xseq, se, level, nboot=200) {
    pred <- MeanResponse(xseq, model$parameters)
    if (!se) {
        return(base::data.frame(x=xseq, y=pred))
    }
    ## bootstrap residuals
    pred0 <- MeanResponse(model$data$Dose, model$parameters)
    res <- pred0-model$data$Response
    bootres <- matrix(nrow=length(xseq), ncol=nboot)
    pb <- txtProgressBar(max=nboot,style=3)
    for (i in seq(nboot)) {
        setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
        mboot <- dr4pl(model$data$Dose,
                       pred0 + sample(res, size=length(pred0),
                                      replace=TRUE))
        bootres[,i] <- MeanResponse(xseq, mboot$parameters)
    }
    fit <- data.frame(x = xseq,
                      y=pred,
                      ymin=apply(bootres,1,quantile,(1-level)/2),
                      ymax=apply(bootres,1,quantile,(1+level)/2))
    return(fit)
}

print(ggplot(dd, aes(dose,POC))
    + geom_point()
    + geom_smooth(method="dr4pl",se=TRUE) + coord_trans(x="log10")
)
```

[image]

Comment: HI Ben, Thanks very much for tackling this. I presume you changed my dataset to 'dd' instead of 'data', but what is 'sample-data_1'? 

Your first block of code runs, but the graph generated is not the one you've shown.
'''> ggplot(dd, aes(dose,POC)) + geom_point() +
+   geom_smooth(method="dr4pl",se=TRUE) + coord_trans(x="log10")
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x''''
The plot which I cannot paste here has no line on it. 

Regarding use of '''geom_smooth''' you've not given the data used so I can't test it. Could you explain the changes to sample_data_1 to run this code please?

Comment: see edits. `sample_data_1` is a data file included with `dr4pl`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the clarification. Again, sorry to be a pain, but the 
'''ggplot(dd, aes(dose,POC)) + geom_point() +
     geom_smooth(method="dr4pl",se=TRUE) + coord_trans(x="log10")''' code does not generate the graph you've posted. What could I change to fix this? I have run on two different pcs and the second time I get the same incorrect graph without a line but also the following error '''Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
there is no package called ‘car’ '''

Comment: '''xseq <- if (is.null(newdata)) object$data$Dose else newdata$x
    pred <- MeanResponse(xseq, object$parameters)''' Are there objects in here that I have not defined? i.e. "data$Dose". If we renamed the "data" to "dd", and the column is headed "dose" then what is "data" and "Dose".

Comment: you need to install the `car` package ... (I should put in a statement `if (!require("car")) warning("...")`)

Comment: I installed "car" and loaded it. Ran again:
'''
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
object 'nfl' of mode 'function' was not found'''
No luck I'm afraid

Comment: It's going to be hard for me to debug this remotely. `packageVersion("car")`?  Does the code work with `se=FALSE` (you would lose the confidence intervals, but maybe that's for the best anyway)?

Comment: Hi, I have recopied everything from your code, wondeful, works a treat, sorry for whatever I did wrong the last time. Ben you've massively helped me out.