# Calculate and plot 95% confidence intervals of a generalised nonlinear model

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, non-linear-regression, nlme

I have built several generalised nonlinear least squares models (exponential decay) with the `R` package *nlme* and the contained `gnls()` function. The reason I do not simply build nonlinear least squares models with the base `nls()` function is because I want to be able to model heteroskedasticity to avoid transformation. My models looks something like this:

```
model <- gnls(Response ~ C * exp(k * Explanatory1) + A,
              start = list(C = c(C1,C1), k = c(k1,k1), A = c(A1,A1)),
              params = list(C ~ Explanatory2, k ~ Explanatory2, 
                            A ~ Explanatory2),
              weights = varPower(), 
              data = Data)
```

The key difference to a simple `nls()` model is the `weights` argument, which enables the modelling of heteroskedasticity by the explanatory variable(s). The linear equivalent to `gnls()` is generalised least squares, which is run with the `gls()` function of *nlme*.

Now I would like to calculate confidence intervals in `R` and plot them alongside my model fit in `ggplot()` (*ggplot2* package). The way I would do this for a `gls()` object is this:

```
NewData <- data.frame(Explanatory1 = c(...), Explanatory2 = c(...)) 
NewData$fit <- predict(model, newdata = NewData)
```

Up to this stage everything works fine and I get my model fit.

```
modmat <-  model.matrix(formula(model)[-2], NewData)
int <- diag(modmat %*% vcov(model) %*% t(modmat))
NewData$lo <- with(NewData, fit - 1.96*sqrt(int))
NewData$hi <- with(NewData, fit + 1.96*sqrt(int))
```

This part doesn't work with `gnls()` so I cannot obtain my upper and lower model predictions.

Since this does not seem to work for `gnls()` objects, I have consulted textbooks as well as previously asked questions but none seem to fit my need. The only similar question I found was  [How to calculate confidence intervals for Nonlinear Least Squares in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341287/how-to-calculate-confidence-intervals-for-nonlinear-least-squares-in-r). In the top answer it was suggested to use either `investr::predFit()` or to build a model with `drc::drm()` and then use the regular `predict()` function. None of these solutions help me with `gnls()`.

My current best solution is to calculate 95% confidence intervals for all three parameters (C, k, A) with the `confint()` function and then write two separate functions for the upper and lower confidence bounds, i.e. one using Cmin, kmin and Amin and one using Cmax, kmax and Amax. Then I use these functions to predict values that I then plot with `ggplot()`. However, I am not entirely satisfied with the result and am not sure if this approach is optimal.

Here is a minimal reproducible example, ignoring the second, categorical explanatory variable for simplicity:

```
# generate data
set.seed(10)
x <-  rep(1:100,2)
r <- rnorm(x, mean = 10, sd = sqrt(x^-1.3))
y <- exp(-0.05*x) + r
df <-  data.frame(x = x, y = y)

# find starting values
m <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, A, C, logk))
summary(m) # A = 9.98071, C = 10.85413, logk = -3.14108
plot(m) # clear heteroskedasticity

# fit generalised nonlinear least squares
require(nlme)
mgnls <- gnls(y ~ C * exp(k * x) + A, 
              start = list(C = 10.85413, k = -exp(-3.14108), A = 9.98071),
              weights = varExp(),
              data = df)
plot(mgnls) # more homogenous

# plot predicted values 
df$fit <- predict(mgnls)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x, fit)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

**Edit following Ben Bolker's answer**

The standard nonparametric bootstrapping solution applied to a second simulated dataset, which is closer to my original data and includes a second, categorical explanatory variable:

```
# generate data
set.seed(2)
x <- rep(sample(1:100, 9), 12)
set.seed(15)
r <- rnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 200*x^-0.8)
y <- c(200, 300) * exp(c(-0.08, -0.05)*x) + c(120, 100) + r
df <-  data.frame(x = x, y = y, 
                  group = rep(letters[1:2], length.out = length(x)))

# find starting values
m <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, A, C, logk))
summary(m) # A = 108.9860, C = 356.6851, k = -2.9356
plot(m) # clear heteroskedasticity

# fit generalised nonlinear least squares
require(nlme)
mgnls <- gnls(y ~ C * exp(k * x) + A, 
              start = list(C = c(356.6851,356.6851), 
                           k = c(-exp(-2.9356),-exp(-2.9356)), 
                           A = c(108.9860,108.9860)),
              params = list(C ~ group, k ~ group, A ~ group),
              weights = varExp(),
              data = df)
plot(mgnls) # more homogenous

# calculate predicted values 
new <- data.frame(x = c(1:100, 1:100),
                  group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 100))
new$fit <- predict(mgnls, newdata = new)

# calculate bootstrap confidence intervals
bootfun <- function(newdata) {
  start <- coef(mgnls)
  dfboot <- df[sample(nrow(df), size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE),]
  bootfit <- try(update(mgnls,
                        start = start,
                        data = dfboot),
                 silent = TRUE)
  if(inherits(bootfit, "try-error")) return(rep(NA, nrow(newdata)))
  predict(bootfit, newdata)
}

set.seed(10)
bmat <- replicate(500, bootfun(new))
new$lwr <- apply(bmat, 1, quantile, 0.025, na.rm = TRUE)
new$upr <- apply(bmat, 1, quantile, 0.975, na.rm = TRUE)

# plot data and predictions
require(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x, y, colour = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = new, aes(x = x, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, fill = group), 
              alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(data = new, aes(x, fit, colour = group)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

This is the resulting plot, which looks neat!

Comment: Either bootstrapping or the delta method would be reasonable approaches in this case. Both approaches are illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806526/plotting-dr4pl-dose-response-curves-and-how-to-integrate-them-with-ggplot2/66809664#66809664), for a different nonlinear model ... If you want to post a [mcve] I can try to show an application to your problem.

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the helpful reply. I added the requested minimal reproducible example and would greatly appreciate if you illustrate your suggested solution.

Comment: Looks awesome. However, I get an error in the code after #Calculate predicted values. My system responds "'contrasts.arg' argument must be named."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implemented a bootstrapping solution. I initially did standard nonparametric bootstrapping, which resamples *observations*, but this produces 95% CIs that look suspiciously wide — I *think* that this is because that form of bootstrapping fails to maintain the balance in the x-distribution (e.g. by resampling you could end up with no observations for small values of x). (It's also possible that there's just a bug in my code.)

As a second shot I switched to resampling the *residuals* from the initial fit and adding them to the predicted values; this is a fairly standard approach e.g. in bootstrapping time series (although I'm ignoring the possibility of autocorrelation in the residuals, which would require *block bootstrapping*).

Here's the basic bootstrap resampler.

```r
df$res <- df$y-df$fit
bootfun <- function(newdata=df, perturb=0, boot_res=FALSE) {
    start <- coef(mgnls)
    ## if we start exactly from the previously fitted coefficients we end
    ## up getting all-identical answers? Not sure what's going on here, but
    ## we can fix it by perturbing the starting conditions slightly
    if (perturb>0) {
        start <- start * runif(length(start), 1-perturb, 1+perturb)
    }
    if (!boot_res) {
        ## bootstrap raw data
        dfboot <- df[sample(nrow(df),size=nrow(df), replace=TRUE),]
    } else {
        ## bootstrap residuals
        dfboot <- transform(df,
                            y=fit+sample(res, size=nrow(df), replace=TRUE))
    }
    bootfit <- try(update(mgnls,
                      start = start,
                      data=dfboot),
                   silent=TRUE)
    if (inherits(bootfit, "try-error")) return(rep(NA,nrow(newdata)))
    predict(bootfit,newdata=newdata)
}
```

```r
set.seed(101)
bmat <- replicate(500,bootfun(perturb=0.1,boot_res=TRUE))   ## resample residuals
bmat2 <- replicate(500,bootfun(perturb=0.1,boot_res=FALSE)) ## resample observations
## construct envelopes (pointwise percentile bootstrap CIs)
df$lwr <- apply(bmat, 1, quantile, 0.025, na.rm=TRUE)
df$upr <- apply(bmat, 1, quantile, 0.975, na.rm=TRUE)
df$lwr2 <- apply(bmat2, 1, quantile, 0.025, na.rm=TRUE)
df$upr2 <- apply(bmat2, 1, quantile, 0.975, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now draw the picture:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), colour=NA, alpha=0.3) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr2, ymax=upr2), fill="red", colour=NA, alpha=0.3) +
    geom_line(aes(y=fit)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

The pink/light-red region is the observation-level bootstrap CIs (suspicious); the gray region is the residual bootstrap CIs.

[image: curve with bootstrap CIs]

It would be nice to try the delta method as well but (1) it makes stronger assumptions/approximations than bootstrapping anyway and (2) I'm out of time.

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to illustrate your solution! The issue you stumbled across may have something to do with the data I initially simulated, since your solution works fine without perturbing or residual resampling on a newly generated dataset (see my edit). I think your residual method would't work on the newly generated data anyway?. One thing I noticed when applying standard nonparametric bootstrapping to my data was a bulge in only one of the confidence intervals despite a similar data distribution in both groups (see the partial plot). Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?