# Non-linear least squares in R: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object not found

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, nls, nonlinear-functions, log-likelihood

I am trying to fit a `gnls` function in R and throws me an error that says:
`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object A not found` Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
set.seed(111)
y.size <- rnorm(100,4,1)
p <- rnorm(100,5,1)

df <- data.frame(p, y.size)

# fit generalised nonlinear least squares
require(nlme)
mgnls <- gnls(y.size ~  ((A *((p*K/Ka)-1))-1)* log(p), 
              start = list(A = c(-1,-10), 
                           K = c(800,3000), 
                           Ka = c(35000,45000)),
              data = df)
plot(mgnls) # more homogenous
```

For anyone needing more info: I'm trying to follow along [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67021669/6820344)

Comment: First you have more parameters, You should only have 2 parameters in your equation, you have 3 parameters

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why can't I have 3 parameters? It's a non-linear polynomial

Comment: Because if you open the paranthesis, one parameter is just a multiplication of the others making it irrelevant eg if you have `y~A*B*C*x` IS not worth it, just have `y~A*x`

Comment: Also why not use `nls` why mult you use `gnls`?

Comment: I am not farmiliar with mle. Though its easy to write a quick function which shall return NA in the case whereby A is not in the bounds. for `K_Ka` you will have the bounds as min = 800/45000, max = 3000/3500

Comment: Also note that the answer given already has the conditions satisfied

Comment: @onyambu Thanks I'll see if I can find a few examples to produce NA's when condition isn't met. Thank you for your valuable input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there are 2 issues. First I don't understand the convention `list(A = c(-1,-10), K = c(800,3000),Ka = c(35000,4500))`.  Generally only 1 value is used to initialize the starting value.

Second, your equation defines K/Ka with both values as adjustable parameters.  This will cause errors since there are an infinite number of values for K and Ka which will evaluate to the same value.  It is better to set one value to a constant or define a new value equal to the ratio.

```
set.seed(111)
y.size <- rnorm(100,4,1)
p <- rnorm(100,5,1)

df <- data.frame(p, y.size)

# fit generalised nonlinear least squares
require(nlme)
mgnls <- gnls(y.size ~  ((A *((p*K_Ka)-1))-1)* log(p), 
              start = list(A = -5,   K_Ka = 0.5),
               data=df)
plot(mgnls) # more homogenous
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to lace bounds in the list. Specifically, to have A between -1 to -10 and K_Ka also to have some ratio maybe less than 1. I am not sure how else to specify the bounds

Comment: @Biotechgeek in that case you will have to use `optim`, not `nls`

Comment: @onyambu Does `mle` do the same job as optim?

Comment: Sorry for commenting on your answer. I have already upvoted. My last comment

Comment: @onyambu, thanks for the additional info. Glad the community is working the way it should.