# Plot 4-parameter logistic model with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, logistic-regression

I am trying to plot results from a 4 parameter logistic regression with `ggplot`.
y= (`q1`) diversity measures for bird dataset, x = (`FC600`) Forest cover measures.

```r
data$q1
 [1] 13.873635 13.377120 11.099290 11.481513  7.989731
 [6]  9.750019 12.737163 12.971196 12.413030 11.576204
[11] 13.909131 14.801793 11.270471 11.126155 13.620503
[16] 11.092484 11.651279 11.304653 13.736830

data$FC600
 [1]  42.70  23.83  12.08  20.46  29.91  27.69  25.87  30.60
 [9]  12.65  36.73  58.05  42.75  34.00  34.33  86.49  20.58
[17]  78.97  10.90 100.00
```

Here is my code:

```r
logip=function(p,mean,x){
  a=p[1]
  b=p[2]
  c=p[3]
  d=p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(data$FC600))/c)))
  -sum(dnorm(x,mean=Riq1, log=TRUE))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log6=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=max(data$q1),
                                         b=mean(data$FC600), 
                                         c=3,
                                         d=min(data$q1)),
                data=list(x=data$q1))

coefs=(cc <- coef(modTR.log6))
coefs=as.data.frame(coefs)
```

Plotting from the coefs obtained looks fine, but I'd like to improve my graph with ggplot-

```r
plot(data$FC600,data$q1, xlab="Forest cover", ylab="Richness",xlim=c(0,100))#original data
curve (coefs[4, 1]+(coefs[1, 1]/(1+exp((coefs[2, 1]-x)/coefs[3, 1]))), add=T,lwd=1.5)
```

I would really appreciate your help, I'm not an expert in R, I've tried with `ggplot` including the formula but is not working =(. I would like to add SE or 95% confidence intervals too.

Comment: you will either need to generate a separate data set with the predictions *or* use `geom_function()` with the coefficients plugged in.  95% confidence intervals for nonlinear models are a little tricky. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806526/plotting-dr4pl-dose-response-curves-and-how-to-integrate-them-with-ggplot2/66809664#66809664) for an example of creating nonlinear function fits in ggplot (there's already a `predict` method for `mle2` objects, you don't need to write that yourself).

Comment: For this problem (nonlinear least-squares) you don't really need `mle2`, you could use `nlme::gls`: . `gls(q1 ~ SSfpl(FC600, ...), data = ...)`